# getItemCount() in Recyclerview adapter returns 0 after asyncTask execution

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use `Asynctask` in custom adapter with `RecyclerView`, but the holders are empty. At First time im getting 0 in `getItemCount();` I can't understand what did i miss. Please help.

```
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
 new initTimeline().execute();
        Log.e("ICLength", String.valueOf(Length));
        return Length;
       }

      private class initTimeline extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
                try {
                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                     ..............
           }return jsonObject1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            Log.e("AfterPE", String.valueOf(json));
            Length = json.length();
            Log.e("AfterPELen", String.valueOf(Length));
           pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
02-10 02:33:17.867 4002-4002/com.example.mir E/ICLength: 0
02-10 02:33:19.057 4002-4002/com.example.mir E/AfterPE: {"id":"22","project_id":"2","date":"2015-11-30","description":"in progress"}
02-10 02:33:19.057 4002-4002/com.example.mir E/AfterPELen: 6
```

i am getting the value of Length correctly in `onPostExecute`,but
`int getItemCount()` returns zero.
Please help.

Comment: its obvious that once you start async task it will get data and u will get count but in method executions move forward and at that time size is zero. what i mean compiler will not stop until asynctask complete and then return data. it will move forward with asynctask.

Comment: Is it possible that at the time you call ``getItemCount()`` the AsyncTask isn't finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `getItemCount()` you start an asynchronous call to your web service. 
Before this call finishes, `getItemCount()` already returned 0.

You will have to inform your adapter that your data has changed when your AsyncTask finished executing. A call to `notifyDatasetChanged` should do this for you:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        Log.e("AfterPE", String.valueOf(json));
        Length = json.length();
        Log.e("AfterPELen", String.valueOf(Length));
        pDialog.dismiss();
        notifyDatasetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Jörn Buitink: thanks , but  `notifyDatasetChanged();` seems cannot resolve method. any other suggestions please..?

Answer (score 3):

you are making a asynchronous call. Your async task is on a worker thread which is running parallely with the main thread.  The first time you are returning length, your task wouldn't have fetched the count till that time.